Compare the run duration of multiple runs of a DLT pipeline
I need to compare the performance of multiple pipeline runs, like time it took to complete.
I have been trying to query the event logs of the pipeline but that does not contain information for the time the pipeline took to execute.
Basically, the aim is to find a query that can find the pipeline run which ran the quickest.
Any ideas if this is possible?


SELECT event_type, SUM(double(details:flow_progress.metrics.executor_time_ms)) total_executor_time_ms
FROM 
  event_log_raw,
  latest_update
  WHERE
  event_type ='flow_progress'
  group by event_type



Ive only managed to sum the executor_time_ms to get the total executor_time_ms.
Can this be considered as the duration for the pipeline run?
there surely is a better way.
Please help

You need to query using Update details like update id and update_progress.
Below is the details in portal.

Here, if you see the runtime is 27s.
First, create event_log_raw table from the delta live tables schema.
CREATE  OR  REPLACE TEMP VIEW event_log_raw AS  SELECT  *  FROM delta.`dbfs:/dlt_temp/system/events/`;

dlt_temp is my schema where all tables and logs stored.
Next, use below query to get the total time taken by each update in the same pipeline.
SELECT
  event_type, origin.update_id, max(timestamp) maxi,min(timestamp) mini, timestampdiff(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp)) total_duration_secs
FROM
  event_log_raw
WHERE event_type=='update_progress'
GROUP BY event_type,origin.update_id
ORDER BY maxi DESC

Here, i filtered the records for  update_progress and done group by on each update and event type.
output;



event_type
update_id
maxi
mini
total_duration_secs




update_progress
daa08062-c10e-458e-aa8d-b5fab66de380
2024-04-11T09:19:48.874+00:00
2024-04-11T09:19:21.413+00:00
27


update_progress
e761c89d-60f9-491e-b27b-279143726178
2024-04-11T09:15:19.459+00:00
2024-04-11T09:14:45.766+00:00
33


update_progress
bfddfb90-9acd-4afc-a88f-397398fc099e
2024-04-11T08:55:02.337+00:00
2024-04-11T08:54:42.075+00:00
20


update_progress
4bea13a7-dee0-4a7e-988b-868dd74d0d4d
2024-04-11T08:53:43.013+00:00
2024-04-11T08:48:42.194+00:00
300



You can also get the latest update details by giving limit 1, since we are sorted this record on timestamp descending.

EDIT
For getting time duration for the tables for specific update use below query.
SELECT
origin.flow_name, max(timestamp) maxi,min(timestamp) mini, timestampdiff(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp)) total_duration_secs
FROM
  event_log_raw,
  (SELECT
  event_type, origin.update_id, max(timestamp) maxi,min(timestamp) mini, timestampdiff(SECOND,min(timestamp),max(timestamp)) total_duration_secs
FROM
  event_log_raw
WHERE event_type=='update_progress'
GROUP BY event_type,origin.update_id
ORDER BY maxi DESC limit 1) b
WHERE 
timestamp>=b.mini and timestamp<=b.maxi and origin.flow_name='target_table'
GROUP BY origin.flow_name

Here, i have used limit 1 in inner query to get latest update time frame details and used it for getting duration for table target_table

if I am saving to unity catalog, where would the event logs be saved?

You don't have to search for path just give
SELECT * FROM event_log("pipeline_id")  or CREATE VIEW event_log_raw AS SELECT * FROM event_log("<pipeline-ID>"); 

Refer this for more info  https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/observability.html#unity-catalog

Thanks @JayashankarGS. One final thing, can I also query for multiple objects executed in the same pipeline?

Do you mean each table?

Yes. For each table that is mapped to a pipeline run

You need to query on flow_name with update details timeframe. I have edited the solution check it out.
